# Alfresco - HTTP Sessions

Tags: javascript, alfresco

Trying to access the HTTP session through Javascript Webscripts on QuickStart.

I am unable to find any help in saving elements to some private object for each http session.

Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a custom JavaScript root object - it is a Java class which implements `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.processor.BaseProcessorExtension` class, for example:

   ```
   package pl.test;

   import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

   import org.springframework.extensions.surf.ServletUtil;
   import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.processor.BaseProcessorExtension;

   public class HttpSessionHelper extends BaseProcessorExtension {

   public void setInSession(String paramName, String paramValue) {
       HttpSession session = ServletUtil.getSession();
       session.setAttribute(paramName, paramValue);
   }

   public String getFromSession(String paramName) {
       HttpSession session = ServletUtil.getSession();

       Object paramValue = session.getAttribute(paramName);
       if (paramValue != null) {
           return paramValue.toString();
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Compile and package this class to jar archive and copy it to Share (or Surf based application).
3. Register this class in spring-surf-script-services-context.xml, for example:

   ```
   <bean id="exampleExtension" parent="baseScriptExtension" 
         class="pl.test.HttpSessionHelper">
     <property name="extensionName">
        <value>httpSessionHelper</value>
     </property>
   </bean>
   ```
4. Use your new custom root object in webscript, for example:

   ```
   var paramName = httpSessionHelper.getFromSession('paramName');
   httpSessionHelper.setInSession('paramName','paramValue');
   ```